# Setting different network profiles with multiple unidentified networks

Tags: windows, networking

I have a machine with three networks:

- public IP identified as "Public" in the group "Network"
- public IP identified as "Public" in the group "Unidentified network"
- private IP identified "Public" also in the group "Unidentified network"

Whenever I try to change the private IP network to "Private" the second network also switches to "Private".

I assume it's because they are grouped together in "Unidentified network". But I have no idea how to separate them (by somehow making them identified I guess).

Answer (score 0):

There are only two basic network settings of this type for a connection: Public and Private.  There is not a third setting.

"Public" turns OFF network discovery and file/print sharing and "Private"  turns these settings ON.   Settings Screen Shot provided below.

You can check what type for each wireless connection by using Windows 10 Settings, OR, by selecting Properties in the Network Connection. That takes you to the same Windows 10 setting.

In your network connection icon in the System Tray, a network may be unidentified - It will very likely be Public.

Also, in this area when you set up a connection, your answer controls Public or Private, even the the language style is different.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not looking for a third setting. I'm asking why my second Public network changes to Private when I set the other.

Comment: Network type may change depending on the network you select . If you allow to trust in a home network it will set to Private. I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

They could also be 2 parts of the same network, but since it doesn't identify it properly, it shows up as two, and inherits settings of the other.

Try flushing it from your system using `ipconfig /flushdns` in cmd
But make sure to select the correct adapter, else you will have to set up the other ones as well. More on ipconfig syntax:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "2 parts of the same network"? As I mentioned the problem occurs with a public IP on network A and a private IP on network B.